# ¿Porque no me deja crear un JPanel con botones y añadirlo en la parte norte de otro JPanel que tiene un BorderLayout?

Tags: java, layout, jpanel

He empezado hace poco a aprender java y al intentar hacer un programa tengo el problema de que he creado un JPanel con un springLAyout y 3 botones que si lo uso solo en un programa aparece, pero si lo intento meter dentro de la parte norte de otro layout no aparece. Seguramente sea un error tonto por ser nuevo  pero me vendría muy bien que alguien me lo explicase.Este es el codigo del JPanel:

```
public class Lamina extends JPanel{
    
    public Lamina()
    {
        setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        
        JPanel lamina_botones = new JPanel();
        JButton boton1 = new JButton("Boton 1");
        JButton boton2 = new JButton("Boton 2");
        
        SpringLayout mi_layout = new SpringLayout();
        lamina_botones.setLayout(mi_layout);
        
        lamina_botones.add(boton1);
        lamina_botones.add(boton2);
        
        Spring muelle = Spring.constant(0,10,100);
        
        mi_layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST,boton1,muelle,SpringLayout.WEST,lamina_botones);
        mi_layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST,boton2,muelle,SpringLayout.EAST,boton1);
        mi_layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST,lamina_botones,muelle,SpringLayout.EAST,boton2);
        
        add(lamina_botones,BorderLayout.NORTH);
     }

}
```

Y esto es lo que se ve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Basicamente está todo azul. Lo he probado con blanco y amarillo y se quedan siempre la pantalla de un mismo color.

No se si importa pero el JFrame es de 1000px por 1000px